# Show record from db only one time to user

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, mysqli

I want to show a new record to a user only one time. I know it can be achieved by using cookies, but how to use it in this situation?
i have all record in $row .

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dentistf_new_df");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM wp_blog_posts order by ID desc ");



while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {


    if(in_array($row['ID'], $_COOKIE['blog_id _status'])) {
        do nothing...
    } else {
        echo $row['ID'];
        setcookie('blog_id _status', $row['ID']);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add the userids in the db who have visited the post .

Answer (score 0):

When You set a data to cookie with [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on one page, You can do this one the second page:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mydata'])) {
    echo $_COOKIE['mydata'];
    setcookie("mydata", "", time()-(60*60*24), "/"); // unsets cookie
}
```

Dont use `$_COOKIE['blog_id _status']  = '';` to set value to Your cookies.

Comment: ok ,but what condition should be given in while loop so that i can display new record one time only

Comment: Why can't You just add condition in MySQL query?

Comment: i can't give condition in mysql query because same record is visible to other user . i use it for the purpose of notification. Means any thing new happen to table

Comment: Then, maybe You should create two queries? One for all users, and one for only particular ones?

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are outside of your control; the users can delete them at any time at which point you will again show them records they have seen before.

Without knowing more details about your data it's hard to provide an exact solution, but I suggest recording in the database, which records a particular user has seen. 

Depending on your data you might be able to achieve this, e.g. by adding a timestamp to each record and storing a "last_timestamp_shown" for each user in a separate table. Then you would have to extend your SELECT statement to only include records with a timestamp that is newer than the "last_timestamp_shown" for this particular user.